# Is it possible to use stacked expressions / to specify more than one parameter for `CustomFormat` in Delphi LiveBindings?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, livebindings

I want to specify

```
LinkControlToDate.CustomFormat := 'IfThen(%s=0, '''', FormatDateTime(''ddddd'', %s))'
```

for the property `CustomFormat` of a `TLinkControlToField` to handle 0 date values.

But this yields a `EConvertError`

> 'no argument for format 'IfThen(%s=0, '', FormatDateTime''

Is it not possible to use a function inside a function with `CustomFormat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the parameter `%s` twice, but there is only one parameter.

Try

```
LinkControlToDate.CustomFormat := 'IfThen(%s=0, '''', FormatDateTime(''ddddd'', %:0s))'
```

Use an index specifier for the second `%s`.